# Jquery Mobile Swipe not work when page has some childs

Tags: jquery, html, jquery-mobile, swipe

I want to use jquery mobile swipe for my mobile application,
I use following code:

```
    $(document).on('pageinit', function () {
    $('img').on('dragstart', function (event) { event.preventDefault(); });
    function navnext(next) {
        //$(":mobile-pagecontainer").pagecontainer("change", next + ".html", {
        //    transition: "slide"
        //});
        $.mobile.changePage(next + ".html", { transition: "slide" });
    }

    // Handler for navigating to the previous page
    function navprev(prev) {
        //$(":mobile-pagecontainer").pagecontainer("change", prev + ".html", {
        //    transition: "slide"
        //});
        $.mobile.changePage(prev + ".html", { transition: "slide" });
    }

    // Navigate to the next page on swipeleft
    $(document).on("swipeleft", ".ui-page *", function (event) {
        // Get the filename of the next page. We stored that in the data-next
        // attribute in the original markup.
        var next = $(this).jqmData("next");

        // Check if there is a next page and
        // swipes may also happen when the user highlights text, so ignore those.
        // We're only interested in swipes on the page.
        if (next) {
            navnext(next);
        }
    });
    $(document).on("swiperight", ".ui-page *", function (event) {
        var prev = $(this).jqmData("prev");

        if (prev) {
            navprev(prev);
        }
    });

});
```

my code is work fine when page is empty and has no child. but when I add some content and image too my page it doesn't work. why? and how can I fix this bug?

here is my html code :

```
 <div data-role="page" id="home" class="demo-page" data-title="New York" data-dom-cache="true" data-next="relay" data-prev="relay">

    <div id="mainContent" role="main" class="ui-content">
        <link href="css/smarthome.css" rel="stylesheet" />
        <link href="css/jquery.mobile.icons.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
        <link href="css/styles.css" rel="stylesheet" />

        <script src="js/swipe.js"></script>
        <!--<script src="js/swipe-page.js"></script>-->
        <div id="header" data-role="header" data-form="" data-id="header" data-tap-toggle="false">
            <div data-role="navbar">
                <ul>
                    <li><a href="#home" class="ui-btn-active ui-btn ui-icon-home ui-btn-icon-left">home</a></li>
                    <li><a href="relay.html"  data-transition="slide">Relay</a></li>
                </ul>
            </div>

        </div><!-- /header -->
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-lg-2 col-md-3 col-sm-3 col-xs-12">
                <div class="col-lg-12 col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-6">
                    <div class="">
                        <a href="#" class="ui-btn ui-btn-b ConnectionState">Connected</a>
                        <!--<a href="#" class="ui-btn ui-btn-c">Disconnected</a>-->
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-lg-12 col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-6">
                    <div class="">
                        <div class="ui-btn btnVoltage Valid">221 V</div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-lg-10 col-md-9 col-sm-9 col-xs-12">
                <div id="container"></div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-4 col-sm-4 col-xs-6">
                <div class="btnRelay active on">
                    <img class="btnOn" src="images/RelayOn.png" />
                    <img class="btnOff" src="images/RelayOff.png" />
                    <img class="btnDeactivate" src="images/RelayDiactive.png" />

                    <div class="name">رله شماره 1 - آشپزخانه</div>
                    <!--<div class="relayState relayoff">
                            <div class="on">
                                ON
                            </div>
                            <div class="off">
                                OFF
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="relayname"><div class="number">R1 </div><div class="name">آشپزخانه</div></div>-->
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-4 col-sm-4 col-xs-6">
                <div class="btnRelay active on">
                    <img class="btnOn" src="images/RelayOn.png" />
                    <img class="btnOff" src="images/RelayOff.png" />
                    <img class="btnDeactivate" src="images/RelayDiactive.png" />
                    <div class="name">رله شماره 1 - آشپزخانه</div>
                    <!--<div class="relayState relayon">
                            <div class="on">
                                ON
                            </div>
                            <div class="off">
                                OFF
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="relayname"><div class="number">R2 </div><div class="name">سالن پذیرایی</div></div>-->
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-4 col-sm-4 col-xs-6">
                <div class="btnRelay active off">
                    <img class="btnOn" src="images/RelayOn.png" />
                    <img class="btnOff" src="images/RelayOff.png" />
                    <img class="btnDeactivate" src="images/RelayDiactive.png" />
                    <div class="name">رله شماره 1 - آشپزخانه</div>
                    <!--<div class="relayState relayoff">
                            <div class="on">
                                ON
                            </div>
                            <div class="off">
                                OFF
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="relayname"><div class="number">R3 </div><div class="name">اتاق خواب</div></div>-->
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-4 col-sm-4 col-xs-6">
                <div class="btnRelay active on">
                    <img class="btnOn" src="images/RelayOn.png" />
                    <img class="btnOff" src="images/RelayOff.png" />
                    <img class="btnDeactivate" src="images/RelayDiactive.png" />
                    <div class="name">رله شماره 1 - آشپزخانه</div>
                    <!--<div class="relayState relayoff">
                            <div class="on">
                                ON
                            </div>
                            <div class="off">
                                OFF
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="relayname"><div class="number">R4 </div><div class="name">پارکینگ</div></div>-->
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-4 col-sm-4 col-xs-6">
                <div class="btnRelay active on">
                    <img class="btnOn" src="images/RelayOn.png" />
                    <img class="btnOff" src="images/RelayOff.png" />
                    <img class="btnDeactivate" src="images/RelayDiactive.png" />
                    <div class="name">رله شماره 1 - آشپزخانه</div>
                    <!--<div class="relayState relayoff">
                            <div class="on">
                                ON
                            </div>
                            <div class="off">
                                OFF
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="relayname"><div class="number">R5 </div><div class="name"></div></div>-->
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-4 col-sm-4 col-xs-6">
                <div class="btnRelay active on">
                    <img class="btnOn" src="images/RelayOn.png" />
                    <img class="btnOff" src="images/RelayOff.png" />
                    <img class="btnDeactivate" src="images/RelayDiactive.png" />
                    <!--<div class="relayState relayoff">
                            <div class="on">
                                ON
                            </div>
                            <div class="off">
                                OFF
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="relayname"><div class="number">R6 </div><div class="name"></div></div>-->
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-4 col-sm-4 col-xs-6">
                <div class="btnRelay deactive">
                    <img class="btnOn" src="images/RelayOn.png" />
                    <img class="btnOff" src="images/RelayOff.png" />
                    <img class="btnDeactivate" src="images/RelayDiactive.png" />
                    <!--<div class="relayState relayoff">
                            <div class="on">
                                ON
                            </div>
                            <div class="off">
                                OFF
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="relayname"><div class="number">R7 </div><div class="name"></div></div>-->
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-4 col-sm-4 col-xs-6">
                <div class="btnRelay deactive">
                    <img class="btnOn" src="images/RelayOn.png" />
                    <img class="btnOff" src="images/RelayOff.png" />
                    <img class="btnDeactivate" src="images/RelayDiactive.png" />
                    <!--<div class="relayState relayoff">
                            <div class="on">
                                ON
                            </div>
                            <div class="off">
                                OFF
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="relayname"><div class="number">R8 </div><div class="name"></div></div>-->
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-4 col-sm-4 col-xs-6">
                <div class="btnRelay deactive">
                    <img class="btnOn" src="images/RelayOn.png" />
                    <img class="btnOff" src="images/RelayOff.png" />
                    <img class="btnDeactivate" src="images/RelayDiactive.png" />
                    <!--<div class="relayState relayoff">
                            <div class="on">
                                ON
                            </div>
                            <div class="off">
                                OFF
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="relayname"><div class="number">R9 </div><div class="name"></div></div>-->
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-4 col-sm-4 col-xs-6">
                <div class="btnRelay deactive">
                    <img class="btnOn" src="images/RelayOn.png" />
                    <img class="btnOff" src="images/RelayOff.png" />
                    <img class="btnDeactivate" src="images/RelayDiactive.png" />
                    <!--<div class="relayState relayoff">
                            <div class="on">
                                ON
                            </div>
                            <div class="off">
                                OFF
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="relayname"><div class="number">R10 </div><div class="name"></div></div>-->
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-4 col-sm-4 col-xs-6">
                <div class="btnRelay deactive">
                    <img class="btnOn" src="images/RelayOn.png" />
                    <img class="btnOff" src="images/RelayOff.png" />
                    <img class="btnDeactivate" src="images/RelayDiactive.png" />
                    <!--<div class="relayState relayoff">
                            <div class="on">
                                ON
                            </div>
                            <div class="off">
                                OFF
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="relayname"><div class="number">R11 </div><div class="name"></div></div>-->
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-4 col-sm-4 col-xs-6">
                <div class="btnRelay deactive">
                    <img class="btnOn" src="images/RelayOn.png" />
                    <img class="btnOff" src="images/RelayOff.png" />
                    <img class="btnDeactivate" src="images/RelayDiactive.png" />
                    <!--<div class="relayState relayoff">
                            <div class="on">
                                ON
                            </div>
                            <div class="off">
                                OFF
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="relayname"><div class="number">R12 </div><div class="name"></div></div>-->
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div><!-- /content -->

</div>
```

Comment: Change ".ui-page *" to ".ui-page". Including the * means that $(this) is the child element and therefore does not have data-next/data-prev. Either that or change the code in the handler to $(this).closest('.ui-page').jqmData("next");

Comment: @ezanker: please add your answer.thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change `".ui-page *"` to `".ui-page"`.

Including the * means that `$(this)` is the child element and therefore does not have data-next/data-prev.

Either that or change the code in the handler to

```
$(this).closest('.ui-page').jqmData("next");
```